# How to get raw pixel data from Texture2D?

Tags: c#, bitmap, sharpdx, texture2d, rgba

I am trying to get pixel(rgba) values from SharpDX Texture2D and then to assign them to bitmap but i get this wrong image:

[image: distorted screen image]

I know that the problem is when i read values from `srcPtr`(See code below), i think the offsets are wrong...

This is the code:

```
SharpDX.DXGI.Resource screenResource;
OutputDuplicateFrameInformation duplicateFrameInformation;

// Try to get duplicated frame within given time is ms
duplicatedOutput.AcquireNextFrame(5, out duplicateFrameInformation, out screenResource);

// copy resource into memory that can be accessed by the CPU
using (var screenTexture2D = screenResource.QueryInterface<Texture2D>())
    device.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(screenTexture2D, screenTexture);

// Get the desktop capture texture
var mapSource = device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(screenTexture, 0, MapMode.Read, SharpDX.Direct3D11.MapFlags.None);

// Create Drawing.Bitmap
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
{
    var boundsRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);

    // Copy pixels from screen capture Texture to GDI bitmap
    var mapDest = bitmap.LockBits(boundsRect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);

    unsafe
    {
        byte* srcPtr = (byte*)mapSource.DataPointer;
        byte* destPtr = (byte*)mapDest.Scan0;

        var curRowOffs = 0;
        var stride = width * 4;

        byte[] rgbaValues = new byte[width*height*4];

        for (uint y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {

            var index = curRowOffs;


            for (uint x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                // ARGB = bytes [B,G,R,A]
                rgbaValues[index] = srcPtr[index];
                rgbaValues[index + 1] = srcPtr[index + 1];
                rgbaValues[index + 2] = srcPtr[index + 2];
                rgbaValues[index + 3] = srcPtr[index + 3];

                //Copy rgba to bitmap
                destPtr[index + 3] = srcPtr[index + 3];
                destPtr[index + 2] = srcPtr[index + 2];
                destPtr[index + 1] = srcPtr[index + 1];
                destPtr[index] = srcPtr[index];


                index += 4;
            }

            // Increase row offset
            curRowOffs += stride;

        }
    }

    // Release source and dest locks
    bitmap.UnlockBits(mapDest);
    device.ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(screenTexture, 0);
```

What i am doing wrong here?
How to put the raw pixels data into byte array?

Comment: First thing I would try is to use actual `mapDest.Stride` instead of the `width * 4` for the destination index. Because stride is not always width * 4.

Comment: Might be the case that `mapSource` also has something like stride, so you should be using that one also for the source index.